# Export tex document which uses the exam class

Tags: latex, markdown, pandoc, converters

I am struggling with exporting a tex document (see below) which uses the exam class to markdown. Somehow the exam class breaks the default settings of pandoc. In particular the command `pandoc -i mytest.tex -o mytest.md` produces a document with empty content for the question parts.

**Edit:** *I am aware of this old issue of pandoc https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/issues/4023 and included the proposed workaround. However, it does not apply to blanks and multiple choice questions.*

Do you have any idea on how to use pandoc or pandoc-filters in a way that pandoc can handle the question parts and create a markdown document which contains the question parts and the solutions of the tex document?

Here is the sample tex-document

```
\documentclass[answers]{exam}
\usepackage{minted}
\let\oldpart\part
\renewcommand{\part}[1][]{\oldpart[#1]{}}
\begin{document}
\begin{questions}
\question Exercise 1
\begin{parts}
    \part[1] This fills in the \fillin[blanks]
\end{parts}
\question Exercise 2
\begin{parts}
    \part[2] Please tick the \textbf{right} statements
    \begin{checkboxes}
        \CorrectChoice This is correct.
        \choice The correct answer is not this answer.
        \choice This is the wrong answer.
        \CorrectChoice This is right.
    \end{checkboxes}
\end{parts}
\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

### Update 1. Dez

I created a follow-up question to this original question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74646430/2331506)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pandoc doesn't know about the `exam` class and the commands that are defined within. A good method is therefore to provide pandoc with some pseudo-definitions, which just enough info to make it work. In this case, it's seems to be enough to provide a redefinition of `\part` and to treat checkboxes as list items:

```latex
% ignore \part
\renewcommand{\part}[0][1]{}
% Treat checkboxes like an itemized list
\newenvironment{checkboxes}{\begin{itemize}}{\end{itemize}}
\renewcommand{\CorrectChoice}{\item ☒ }
\renewcommand{\choice}{\item ☐ }
```

You can put that into a separate file as not to interfere with the actual LaTeX, and pass it to pandoc as the first file:

```bash
pandoc redefine-part.tex mytest.tex -o test.md
```

With that, the generated Markdown becomes

```markdown
::: questions
Exercise 1

::: parts
This fills in the
:::

Exercise 2

::: parts
Please tick the **right** statements

-   [x] This is correct.

-   [ ] The correct answer is not this answer.

-   [ ] This is the wrong answer.

-   [x] This is right.
:::
:::
```

Nota bene: `-i` **does not** stand for `input` and probably doesn't do what you think.

Comment: Hi @tarleb thanks for your reply and the clarification. Please see that I used a similar redefinition based on the proposed workaround in the github issue. Unfortunately, your suggestions do not really change the markdown output. In particular the text in the blanks is not added and the multiple choice statements are not separated into different lines. Do you have an idea how to fix that?

Comment: @Andy There are now a few more details in the answer, hope it works for you.

Comment: Thanks a lot @tarleb for your clarification and your code. Although the export to markdown works flawlessly, the code results in problems for pdflatex. In particular I get the error ```Command \checkboxes already defined.```and ```Command \CorrectChoice undefined.``` when I try generating a pdf. Do you have an idea whats behind that and how to fix it?

Comment: Happy it works. About PDF: putting the code into a separate file as proposed in the answer should work.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. Sorry for asking you one more time for your help, but I am struggling with the `\fillin`command which just provides broken output. Please see the update above. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please open a new question for this.

Comment: Sorry, yes you are right. I just opend a new question under the link above with a reference to this original answer.