# Export tex document which uses the exam class (Part 2)

Tags: latex, markdown, pandoc, converters

I would like to export a text document which uses the exam class to markdown. To do so, I am currently using a workaround which was suggested in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74363550/2331506), which relies on pseudo-definitions which in turn overwrite the definitions of the exam class such that pandoc can produce a clean markdown file.

Although, the workaround works for the suggested multiple-choice questions, I cannot adopt the solution to work for text with “fillin gaps” such as the document below:

```
\documentclass[answers]{exam}
\usepackage{minted}
\let\oldpart\part
\renewcommand{\part}[1][]{\oldpart[#1]{}}
\begin{document}
\begin{questions}
\question Exercise 1
\begin{parts}
    \part[1] This fills in the \fillin[blanks][3cm]
\end{parts}
\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

If I use the following pseudo-definitions in a separate file:

```
% ignore \part
\renewcommand{\part}[0][1]{}
% Treat checkboxes like an itemized list
\newenvironment{checkboxes}{\begin{itemize}}{\end{itemize}}
\renewcommand{\CorrectChoice}{\item ☒ }
\renewcommand{\choice}{\item ☐ }
\renewcommand\fillin[2][{}]{\textbf{#1}}
```

I get the following broken markdown output

```
This fills in the **blanks**3cm\]
```

Moreover is there a way for pandoc to ignore `\begin{parts}` and `\end{parts}` so that there are no `:::` in the final Markdown file?

Comment: What's the output that you'd *like* to get for `\fillin`?

Comment: I would like to only get textbf for the first bracket so that the missing text in the first bracket is bold in the markdown document, the second bracket can be discarded.

Comment: @whoever voted to migrate to tex.se: Please don't! That's primarily a rmarkdown/pandoc problem. In normal latex one could simply write suitable source code and wouldn't have to work around whatever code the rmarkdown/pandoc produces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `\fillin` problem can be solved with

```latex
\newcommand{\fillin}[1][1]{\textbf{#1}\noop}
```

whereas the `parts` div can be removed with

```latex
\newenvironment{parts}{}{}
```