# Export tex document which uses moodle class

Tags: html, latex, converters, pandoc

I am struggling with exporting a tex document (see below) which uses the moodle class to html using pandoc. At the moment, no metadata is exported but only flat, unstructured, text. I am looking for a way to structure the output into question and solution parts. Moreover, I am looking for a way to print out the number of points for each question.

Based on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74363550/2331506), I would like to use a separate tex file to redefine the particular commands using the command.
`pandoc redefine-part.tex test.tex -o test.html`

My `redefine-part.tex` includes the line, but still outputs the lines in the VerbatimOut Tag

```
\newenvironment{VerbatimOut}{}{}
```

Do you have any idea or hint on how to redefine the **\begin{essay}** and **item** commands such that after calling pandoc the former ends in a regular p-Tag while the latter one will be surrounded by a div-Tag with class "solutionorlines". Finally, do you think it is possible to extract the points from the \begin{essay} part?

```
<p><em>( 2 Punkte )</em> How are you?</p>
<div class="solutionorlines">
<ul>
<li><p>solution no. 1</p></li>
<li><p>solution no. 2</p></li>
</ul>
```

My sample tex document:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[nostamp]{moodle}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % necessary
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % necessary
\usepackage{minted} % Framework for code formatting
\renewcommand\theFancyVerbLine{\normalsize\arabic{FancyVerbLine}}
\begin{document}
\begin{quiz}{My first quiz}
    \setminted{numbersep=3ex,tabsize=4,numberblanklines=false,autogobble=true,style=abap}
    \begin{VerbatimOut}{_minted-test/test.java}
        public class MyTest{
            private String name;
        }
    \end{VerbatimOut}
    \begin{VerbatimOut}{_minted-test/test1.java}
        public class MyTest1{
            private String name;
        }
    \end{VerbatimOut}

    \begin{essay}[response field lines=40, response required=true, response format=text, points=10]{EssayQuestion}
    \inputminted[numbers=left]{java}{_minted-test/test.java}

    \end{essay}
    \begin{essay}[response field lines=20, response required=true, response format=text, points=3]{Wissen-1}
        How are you?
        \item solution no. 1 
        \item solution no. 2
    \end{essay}


\end{quiz}
\end{document}
```